# How can I use List of object with Stripes "option" tag?

Tags: java, stripes

I have a List of object, produced by JPA `q.getResultList()`.

I would like to use it in a drop down, but Stripes "option" tag cant accept List, just `Collection`, `Enum` `and` `Map`.

Im new to Java, that why perhaps the `List` can translated to each of them but I don't know how can I solve this issue.

(Stripes select,option-map,-enumeration, -collection can build up a drop down from previous mentioned input object structures )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation of the **[options-collection](http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/taglib/stripes/options-collection.html)** tag says:

> Writes a set of `<option
>   value="foo">bar</option>` tags to the
>   page based on the contents of a
>   `Collection`, `Iterable` or `Array`. Each
>   element in the collection is
>   represented by a single option tag on
>   the page. Uses the label and value
>   attributes on the tag to name the
>   properties of the objects in the
>   `Collection` that should be used to
>   generate the body of the HTML option
>   tag and the value attribute of the
>   HTML option tag respectively. If
>   either (or both) of the label or value
>   properties are omitted the item
>   itself will be used for the
>   label/value instead - this is done to
>   support collections of simple types
>   like Strings and Numbers.
>
> E.g. a tag declaration that looks
>   like:
>
> ```
> <stripes:options-collection collection="${cats}" value="catId" label="name"/>
> ```
>
> would cause the container to look for
>   a `Collection` called "cats" across the
>   various JSP scopes and set it on the
>   tag. The tag would then proceed to
>   iterate through that collection
>   calling `getCatId()` and `getName()` on
>   each cat to produce HTML option tags.

A **[`java.util.List`](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/List.html)** being a **`Collection`**, just pass it to the `collection` attribute of the mentioned tag.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply, i have tried a list (on the analogy of help and your example), it doesnt work for me.but im sure, it made something wrongly.thanks the quick reply and the effort.

Comment: @cscsaba242 You're welcome. But without seeing your code, I'm afraid I won't be able to provide more help.

Answer (score 1):

A `List` object is a `Collection` object: the the `List` interface extends that of `Collection`. You can use a `List` object, such as `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` in all places where you need a `Collection`.

The `Enum` type is a sort of static list, by declaring a class as being an enum, like so:

```
public enum MyEnum {
    FirstOption, SecondOption, ThirdOption;
}
```

The `Map` type is an associative set; e.g. the `Hashtable`, `HashMap` and `TreeMap` are all instances of a `Map`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, naturally I have used a List of object for a probe. It doesnt work for me. I believe your experience, so the error is in my side.(something wrong in using list)